# Newtonsoft json Serialize Primitive types WebApi

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API project with C# and I am trying to configure the Json Serializer (Newtonsoft JSON) to return always a wrapped response, because when my api controller just returns a Boolean or a integer (or other primitive types), I just get the object but I want something like:

```
{ d : true }
```

a wrapped result but without modifying the controller, i saw that there are a lot of configuration stuff on:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
```

but i don´t found the one that provides this behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you getting at the moment?

Comment: Just "true" or the numbers

Comment: Anyone? Did OP get a solution to this?
E.g. returning a decimal of 0.54 gives exactly that, instead of a wrapped response like { "Result": 0.54 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi finally I solved creating my own Formatter inheriting from JsonMediaTypeFormatter, like this:

```
config.Formatters.Add(new WrappedJsonMediaTypeFormatter());

public class WrappedJsonMediaTypeFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{

        public WrappedJsonMediaTypeFormatter() 
        {
            base.SerializerSettings.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
            base.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        }

        public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task WriteToStreamAsync(System.Type type, object value, System.IO.Stream writeStream, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, System.Net.TransportContext transportContext)
        {
            var obj = value;
            if (type.IsPrimitive || Object.ReferenceEquals(type, typeof(string)))
                obj = new { data = value };

            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(value, null))
                obj = new { };

            return base.WriteToStreamAsync(type, obj, writeStream, content, transportContext);
        }
    }
```